# How to tell mongoose dont give me the users with this and this id?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a simple find that i have to do on users table.
I want to return users with score greater then 70, and those who dont have this nor that id,
What is the way to write it?

```
mongoose.model('User').find(
   {'score' : { $gt: 70 }, '_id' : { $ne : 555 and/or? 666 } }
);
```

What is the correct way to write it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`$nin`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/nin/#op._S_nin) operator to find docs where a field doesn't contain any of the values in an array:

```js
mongoose.model('User').find(
   {'score' : { $gt: 70 }, '_id' : { $nin : [555, 666] } }
);
```